# Random variables for which the distribution of the sum of the RV with a Gaussian RV is known

Tags: distributions, entropy, sum

For a counter example, I am searching for random variables $Y$ such that for a independent normal random variable $X$ the distribution of $Z=Y+X$ is known parametrically. Ideally, the Shannon entropy of $Z$ should also be known.

The obvious case is when $Y$ is normal as well.

Another example would be $Y$ being Bernoulli. In that case, the distribution of $Z$ is a mixture of two Gaussians. However, the entropy of this distribution is unknown.

Are there other/better examples?

Comment: While I can't think of any that have known 'names', it should be reasonably straightforward to derive closed-form solutions. Are there any cases for $Y$ that you are particularly interested in?

Comment: I was basically looking for cases for which the Shannon entropy is known, since I needed a pair of variables that have Gaussian noise but not a Gaussian marginal distribution on $Z$. I used uniform + Gauss now, but if you have others, I'd still be interested in it.